# why Google calls variables with the prefix "m"?

Tags: android

why Google calls variables with the prefix "m" for example:

```
    private int mSectionResourceId;
    private int mTextResourceId;
```

I see it in all examples. But i not understand why they do it?

And now i have some example where it practic very good. If a called variabels without prefix i need write

```
public SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int sectionResourceId, int textResourceId,
                                              RecyclerView.Adapter baseAdapter) {
        this.sectionResourceId = sectionResourceId;
        this.textResourceId = textResourceId;
```

but if i use prefix i can write

```
public SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int sectionResourceId, int textResourceId,
                                              RecyclerView.Adapter baseAdapter) {

        mSectionResourceId = sectionResourceId;
        mTextResourceId = textResourceId;
```

I think it more readable. Who can explain to me the pros and cons of a prefix?

Comment: Short for "member" maybe? And if you has a member variable, it doesn't matter what it's named, from a member function in the same class it can always be accessed directly through its name *or* by using `this`.

Comment: It's only a **naming convention**. You're free not to use it. Or to replace it by somethimg else. i.e.: **_** (underscore). IMO, it decreases the readability.

Comment: Google themselves don't really _call_ it anything as far as I've seen. But [their guideline for contributions](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) to Android reads as follows: _Non-public, non-static field names start with m._

Comment: There is more to consider than just this. Read a [pro m-Notation article](http://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/16/keep-the-m-notation/) which also links to a contra m-Notation article. Feel free to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables starting with **m** are telling you they are variables in the scope of your class. Member of the class.

[Link to Android Code Style Guide](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

The `m` just stands for 'Member'. It is simply declared that your Variable is a Class-Member.
It is more readable Code, because you know where Class Members got declared, so you can find it pretty fast. You don't need to write `this`, even if you don't prefix your Variables with an `m`.

In your Example, `this` only makes it more readable when there is no prefix-m. Another developer knows that it is a instance variable (member variable) and so declared on top or bottom of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It is a prefix for class member variables. It's just a naming convention.

Mostly sure, taken from [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) where similar prefix: `m_` stands for exactly the same).

Referring to pros & cons:

1. Pros:

   - it allows to type fewer chars during programming,
   - programmers that are used to use Hungarian Notation may found it easier to follow the code.
2. Cons:

   - as the code changes very often, it is easy to forget about changing prefixes every time, when variable changes it's purpose (especially during prototyping),
   - it makes the code starts to smell bad,

Generally, it is some kind of reinventing the wheel. Java has `this` keyword that should be more than enough for accessing proper variable. If it's not, the code requires refactoring, maybe because of naming glitches or using too wide variable scopes.

Personally, I do not recommend to use Hungarian Notation (even the part of Android Code Style). We have great IDEs that increases the readability of the code.

There is an exception. The code, where Hungarian Notation (or more general, specific code style) was already been used. It is a matter of [consistency](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#be-consistent).

Answer (score 0):

The m is just a member variable. A class member if you will. Useable with constructors like WebView M WebView then later on you would use something like `mWebView.loadurl("example.com");` it's just a placeholder for the variable you created. You don't have to add the member class variable as an m but it's more organized if you do

Comment: I understand I'm just doing it to make sure I got the point across because I suffer from ADHD and I struggle with it. It's just a manner of putting a common factor to the educational approach maintaining something noticeable. A vulgar statement forces attention and decipher it thus understanding the material. So its true but I want it to click the first time. And if you have ADHD you're gonna get it without having to read over it due to a low and scattering attention span. It works.